# Having in Apache Camel an JMS consumer with 1 ClientID and 2 Topics. How to realize it?

Tags: apache-camel, jms

I have a simple durable subscriber listening to 2 JMS topics using 1 clientID:

```java
@Bean
public void init() {

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ...
    try {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.setExceptionListener(eifErrorListener.defineExceptionListener());
        connection.setClientID("user");
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber1 = subscribe(session, topic1, SubName1);
        TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber2 = subscribe(session, topic2, SubName2);
        if (topicSubscriber1.getMessageListener() != null && topicSubscriber2.getMessageListener() != null) {
            logger.info("Successfully connected and subscribed with " + topicSubscriber1.getTopic().getTopicName() + " and " + topicSubscriber2.getTopic().getTopicName());
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        eifErrorListener.defineExceptionListener().onException(e);
    }
}

private TopicSubscriber subscribe(Session session, String TopicName, String SubName) throws JMSException {
    Topic topic = session.createTopic(TopicName);
    TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, SubName);
    topicSubscriber.setMessageListener( new EIFMessageListner());
    return topicSubscriber;
}
```

Now I want to transfer this example into Apache Camel, but I always get this error message:

```
ClientID already connected from ...
```

Is there a possibility to achieve the same in Apache Camel having one client ID but 2 topics?

Any help, especially a small example would be really appreciated.

I tried the following code, but I receive the aforementioned error message.

EDIT: I have reworked my code to incorporate the idea from Justin, but unfortunately I receive the same error message when running the same:

`javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: myClientID1 already connected from tcp://172.20.0.1:43100`

Is there any idea what can be done to keep 1 ClientID with 2 topics like it is possible in my example above?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```java
 public void configure() throws Exception {

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory ("failover:(tcp://localhost:61617,tcp://localhost:61618)?randomize=false");
        connectionFactory.setClientID("myClientID1");

        // Setting Use Single Connection to True
        ActiveMQComponent amqComponent = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent();
        amqComponent.setUseSingleConnection(true);
        amqComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        amqComponent.setConsumerType(ConsumerType.Simple);

        context.addComponent("active-mq", amqComponent);
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // Configuring Routes
                from("active-mq:topic:TopicA?durableSubscriptionName=DSN1")
                        .to("log:receivedMessages");

                from("active-mq:topic:TopicB?durableSubscriptionName=DSN2")
                        .to("log:receivedMessages");
            }
        });
        context.start();
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it matter that both consumers use the same client ID?

Comment: In my real world case the client as a human consumer is the same person and is subscribing to 2 topics where this consumer receives messages within the same logical process. that's why my thinking, that logically it might be the same client ID.
And as it is feasible with plain Java and ActiveMQ without obvious disadvantages (at least to me, maybe there are some), I thought there was definitely a way in camel to realize it also having the same client ID

Comment: I'm not a Camel expert, but in JMS terms both routes need to use the _same_ JMS connection in order to use the same client ID and I'm not sure if there is a way to force multiple routes to use the same JMS connection. Maybe try using `useSingleConnection=true` on both routes.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks a lot for your advice. Unfortunately using my example above taking into account your idea produces the same error. Is there any idea in addition you may have in mind? Best regards, Michael